# Error al llamar un macro desde otro macro en VBA

Tags: vba

estoy aprendiendo el lenguaje de VBA, y he estado practicando, haciendo una tabla que genere valores aleatorios según una distribución triangular, para esto en una tabla dentro de una hoja coloco los nombres de variables, la moda y el minimo y maximo historico de esa variable. Con esos 3 ultimos parametros genero un vector con los número según la distribución.

Comienzo creando 3 objetos type, uno para las variables, otro para constantes ( estas 2 se usaran para luego hacer un modelo y hallar un valor esperado ) y otro para los escenarios.

Como primer paso estoy creando la macro para generar valores aleatorios en funcion de una distribución, en la primera tomo los valores de cuantos escenarios quiero generar y cuantas variables y constantes ha ingresado el usuario. Luego llamo a la segunda macro que se encarga de generar una tabla con una columna con los escenarios generados para la primera variable ingresada por el usuario. Sin embargo al hacer la llamada al segundo macro me aparece el siguiente error.

[image: este es el error que me sale]

También adjunto el código que he estado avanzando.
Es un poco largo, pero recien estoy aprendiendo, el error me sale luego de llamar al segundo macro desde el primero.

```
    'Generar matriz para variables
Type variable

    nombrev As String
    minh As Double
    vesp As Double
    maxh As Double
    
End Type
'Generar matriz para constantes
Type constante
    
    nombrec As String
    valor As Double
    
End Type

'Generar matriz para los escenarios
Type combinacion

    posicion As Integer
    primer_variable As Integer
    
End Type
Sub generar_escenarios()

Dim nescenarios As Integer
Dim nvariables As Integer
Dim nconstantes As Integer

'Pedir cantidad de escenarios
nescenarios = CInt(InputBox("Coloque cuántos escenarios desea generar", "Generar escenarios", 10))
' Contar cuantas variables hay
nvariables = CInt(WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("c3:g3")))
'Contar cuantas constantes hay
nconstantes = CInt(WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("j3:n3")))

Call dist_triang(nescenarios, nvariables, nconstantes)

End Sub
'Macro para generar la matriz con los valores que obtendrá la tabla
Sub dist_triang(escenarios As Integer, n_variables As Integer, n_constantes As Integer)

Dim cant_escenarios As Integer
cant_escenarios = escenarios
'Almacenar variables
'almacenar_variables (n_variables)
Dim cantidad_variables As Integer
cantidad_variables = n_variables

Dim variables(1 To cantidad_variables) As variable
Dim contadorv As Integer
contadorv = 1
    For v = 3 To 7
        If Sheets(1).Cells(3, v).Value <> Null Then
            variables(contadorv).nombrev = Sheets(1).Cells(3, v).Value
            variables(contadorv).minhv = Sheets(1).Cells(4, v).Value
            variables(contadorv).vesp = Sheets(1).Cells(5, v).Value
            variables(contadorv).maxh = Sheets(1).Cells(6, v).Value
            contadorv = contadorv + 1
         End If
    Next v
'Almacenar constantes
'almacenar_constantes (n_constantes)
Dim cantidad_constantes As Integer
cantidad_constantes = n_constantes

Dim constantes(1 To cantidad_constantes) As constante
Dim contadorc As Integer
contadorc = 1
For v = 10 To 15
    If Sheets(1).Cells(3, v).Value <> Null Then
        constantes(contadorc).nombrev = Sheets(1).Cells(3, v).Value
        constantes(contadorc).minhv = Sheets(1).Cells(4, v).Value
        contadorc = contadorc + 1
     End If
Next v
'*****************************************************************
'Declarar vector con n números aleatorios entre 0 y 1
Dim n_aleatorios(1 To cant_escenarios)
'Almacenar números aleatorios en vector n_aleatorios
For i = 1 To cant_escenarios
    n_aleatorios(i) = Worksheet.Function.rand()
Next i
'******************************************************************
'declarar matriz tipo combinacion que almacenara todos los escenarios
Dim matriz_esc(1 To cant_escenarios) As combinacion
'generar valores segun distribucion triangular para primera variable
For h = 1 To cant_escenarios
    matriz_esc(h).posicion = h
    matriz_esc(h).primer_variable = TRIANGULAR(variables(h).minh, variables(h).vesp, variables(h).maxh, n_aleatorios(h))
Next h
'************************************************
'generar tabla
Dim fin_tabla As Integer
fin_tabla = 13 + cant_escenarios

Sheets(1).Cells(12, 3).Value = variables(1).nombrev

For t = 13 To fin_tabla
    Sheets(1).Cells(t, 2).Value = matriz_esc(1).posicion
    Sheets(1).Cells(t, 3).Value = matriz_esc(1).primer_variable
Next t

End Sub

'funcion para generar número segun distribución triangular sacada de gugol
Public Function TRIANGULAR(a As Double, b As Double, c As Double, P As Single) As Double

   Dim k As Single
   Dim X As Double

   'Calculamos k
   k = (b - a) / (c - a)

   If P < k Then
      X = a + Sqr(P * (b - a) * (c - a))
   Else
      X = c - Sqr((1 - P) * (b - a) * (c - a))
   End If

   TRIANGULAR = X

End Function
```

[image: Este es el modelo de tabla que estoy guardando en la hoja y es de donde tomo los datos]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré el error, al declarar una matriz, la declara de un tamaño que era igual a una variable. Al declararla con Dim nombre_matriz(variable) as objeto_type, el error fue que debí declararla con ReDim, de esta forma ya se sabe que es una matriz dinámica y no pide una constante.